# Render a specific children of a route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router in my reactjs application. I have a route defined for homepage. In this route I have two children routes. It looks like this

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
   <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
   <Route path='/app' onEnter={hasAuth}>
      <IndexRoute component={NewHome}>
         <IndexRoute component={Reviews} />
         <Route path='/search' component={Search} />
      </IndexRoute>
   </Route>
</Route>
```

This  is my home component

```
class NewHomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={c.container}>
                <div className="page-content-wrapper full-height">
                    {/*<!-- START PAGE CONTENT -->*/}
                    <div className="content full-height">
                        <div className="container-fluid container-fluid-media full-height no-padding">
                            <div className="row full-height no-margin">
                                <NewSidebar/>
                                {this.props.children}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**What I want** I want  to render Reviews as default component. But when I click on my profile photo (which is in header) I want the Search component in place of Reviews. Currently even Index route Riviews is also not getting to be shown

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which version of react-router are u using ? What route is called when clicking in profile photo?

Comment: using v4. Second part of your comment is my question. I want Search component in place of Reviews when a certain action is taken. Currently none of them gets shows.

Comment: In the `App` component use `{this.props.children}` to do that.

Comment: In Home Component I am doing that. Why do it need to do it in App component?

Comment: seem home component is same as app in this case

Comment: v4 doesn't have Index route. You need to re-configure your routes according to the router docs

Comment: Kindly check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch).

For profile click define [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) or [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) there.

```
<Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
```

Routers :

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Reviews}></Route>
          <Route path='/profile' component={Search}></Route>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you'd have to make a slight change to your routes like below:

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
    <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
    <Route path='/app' onEnter={hasAuth} component={NewHome}>
      <IndexRoute component={Reviews} />
      <Route path='/search' component={Search} />
    </Route>  
</Route>
```

Then in your `NewHome` component, you would use `{props.children}` if it's a functional/stateless component or `{this.props.children}` if it's a stateful component.

An example is shown below for functional component:
import React from 'react';

```
const NewHome = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewHome;
```

For stateful component, it would look like this:

```
export default class NewHome extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before posting. And my question is how to replace Reviews with Search when a certain button is clicked

Comment: You could make your search into a modal instead of having it as a route.